# How to fix: "integer expected got float"?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am facing this problem in the code below. I can't understand how to fix it. I am a beginner and don't know how to fix it. I can just analyze where it arises.

```
    w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
    w.keypad(1)
    w.timeout(100)
    snk_x = sw/4
    snk_y = sh/2
    snake = [
        [snk_y,snk_x],
        [snk_y,snk_x-1],
        [snk_y,snk_x-2]
    ]


    food = [sh/2,sw/2]
    w.addch(food[0], food[1],curses.ACS_PI) #here in this line i get error
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is incomplete. What language do you use? What have you already tried to find the error?

Answer (score 1):

Either `sh/2` or `sw/2` ends up being a non-integer number (say, `sh` is 25 originally; half of it is 12.5), and curses character positions must be integer.

You can use the truncating division operator `//`, i.e. `sh // 2`, or use `round()`, i.e. `round(sh / 2)`.